# Google sheets API PDF naming

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Working on a project, merging rows to create a PDF and Emailing it.
Can't figure out why my code is not renaming the PDF to the Filename followed by the Name
I am thinking it is something to do with `**var PDF_FILE_NAME**` or `// Self note: Rename the new PDF file` or

```
var FILE_NAME_COLUMN_NAME = 'File Name'
var EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME = 'Email'
var NAME_COLUMN_NAME = 'Name'
```

here is the set of codes and a screenshot of the data.
**Apologies for the self notes and long code. it guides me and educates me to find errors when I work on it**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9coxs.png)

```
// self note:Doc to merge template
var TEMPLATE_ID = '1a1iQGpCo3c4djPcYGtcTZg1uSi1-KA_ZzpzxAcNFcvU'
// self note: to specify name code below
var PDF_FILE_NAME = (FILE_NAME_COLUMN_NAME = 'File Name' + ' '+'testing')
// self note: If Email available will email
var EMAIL_SUBJECT = 'The email subject'
var EMAIL_BODY = 'The email body'

// Self note: where PDF saved on drive    
var RESULTS_FOLDER_ID = '1jZJ9u1BGZu8bfwsFJGcZFz4pkAHBG0K-'
// Self Note: Constants
// Self Note:You can pull out specific columns values 
var FILE_NAME_COLUMN_NAME = 'File Name'
var EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME = 'Email'
var NAME_COLUMN_NAME = 'Name'

var DATE_FORMAT = 'yyyy/MM/dd';

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp
    .getUi()
    .createMenu('[ Create PDFs ]')
    .addItem('Create a PDF for each row', 'createPdfs')
    .addToUi()
} // onOpen()

/**  
 * self note: pick fields, each row in the active sheet to doc to creat pdf
 */

function createPdfs() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  if (TEMPLATE_ID === '') {    
    ui.alert('TEMPLATE_ID needs to be defined in code.gs')
    return
  }
  // self noteSet docs sheet access
  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_ID)
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var allRows = activeSheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  var headerRow = allRows.shift()

  // self Note: Create a PDF for each row
  allRows.forEach(function(row) {
    createPdf(templateFile, headerRow, row)

    /**
     * Create a PDF
     *
     * @param {File} templateFile
     * @param {Array} headerRow
     * @param {Array} activeRow
     */
  
    function createPdf(templateFile, headerRow, activeRow) {
      var headerValue
      var activeCell
      var ID = null
      var recipient = null
      var copyFile
      var numberOfColumns = headerRow.length
      var copyFile = templateFile.makeCopy()      
      var copyId = copyFile.getId()
      var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId)
      var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection()
      for (var columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < numberOfColumns; columnIndex++) {
        headerValue = headerRow[columnIndex]
        activeCell = activeRow[columnIndex]
        activeCell = formatCell(activeCell);
                
        copyBody.replaceText('<<' + headerValue + '>>', activeCell)
        if (headerValue === FILE_NAME_COLUMN_NAME) {
          ID = activeCell
        } else if (headerValue === EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME) {
          recipient = activeCell
        }
      }
      // Self Note: PDF file create
      copyDoc.saveAndClose()
      var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(copyFile.getAs('application/pdf'))  
      copyFile.setTrashed(true)

      // Self note: Rename the new PDF file
      if (PDF_FILE_NAME !== '') {
        newFile.setName(PDF_FILE_NAME)
      } else if (ID !== null){
        newFile.setName(ID)
      }
      
      // Self note PDF put in folder
      if (RESULTS_FOLDER_ID !== '') {
        DriveApp.getFolderById(RESULTS_FOLDER_ID).addFile(newFile)
        DriveApp.removeFile(newFile)
      }

      // Self Note: Email the new PDF
      if (recipient !== null) {
        MailApp.sendEmail(
          recipient, 
          EMAIL_SUBJECT, 
          EMAIL_BODY,
          {attachments: [newFile]})
      }
    } // createPdfs.createPdf()
  })
  ui.alert('New PDF files created')
  return
  
  // Private Functions
  /**
  * Format the cell's value
  *
  * @param {Object} value
  *
  * @return {Object} value
  */
  function formatCell(value) {
    var newValue = value;
    if (newValue instanceof Date) {
      newValue = Utilities.formatDate(
        value, 
        Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 
        DATE_FORMAT);
    } else if (typeof value === 'number') {
      newValue = Math.round(value * 100) / 100
    }
    return newValue;
  } // createPdf.formatCell()
} // createPdfs()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, you want to have the file named into the value under `File Name` if it does exist, if not, then use the default value which is the value of `PDF_FILE_NAME`.

Since `PDF_FILE_NAME` already has a value, it always goes into the `if` condition thus using it instead of the `ID`.

#### Solution:

- Just swap the `if` and `else if` blocks. It will change from this:

  ```
  if (PDF_FILE_NAME !== '') {
    newFile.setName(PDF_FILE_NAME)
  } else if (ID !== null){
    newFile.setName(ID)
  }
  ```
- into this:

  ```
  if (ID !== null){
    newFile.setName(ID)
  } else if (PDF_FILE_NAME !== '') {
    newFile.setName(PDF_FILE_NAME)
  }
  ```

#### Output:

- Screenshot below will show 2 different runs, the last 2 files are outputs from your original code, and the first 2 are outputs using the modified `if/else if`

[image: output]

#### EDIT:

For your additional questions, I will entertain them below:

First is basically add the name after the filename. (`File1 Phil`, `File2 Bob`)

**Step 1**: Add a variable that will hold the name value, let's say `NAME`

```
var ID = null
var NAME = null
var recipient = null
```

**Step 2**: Catch the name value and store it to the variable `NAME`

```
if (headerValue === FILE_NAME_COLUMN_NAME) {
  ID = activeCell
} else if (headerValue === EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME) {
  recipient = activeCell
} else if (headerValue === NAME_COLUMN_NAME) {
  NAME = activeCell
}
```

**Step 3**: Append `NAME` in `setName`

```
if (ID !== null){
  newFile.setName(ID + ' ' + NAME)
} else if (PDF_FILE_NAME !== '') {
  newFile.setName(PDF_FILE_NAME)
}
```

[image: output1]

Second is add the name into the body of the email.

**Step 1**: Change your value into a template.

```
var EMAIL_SUBJECT = 'subject for <<Name>>'
var EMAIL_BODY = 'body for <<Name>>'
```

**Step 2**: Update the template by using `replace` and then store them into another variable and use them. Note that we used the variable `NAME` we created for the first question as it still holds the value.

```
// Update template and replace the variable with NAME
var subject = EMAIL_SUBJECT.replace('<<Name>>', NAME);
var body = EMAIL_BODY.replace('<<Name>>', NAME);

// Self Note: Email the new PDF
if (recipient !== null) {
  MailApp.sendEmail(
    recipient, 
    subject, 
    body,
    {attachments: [newFile]})
}
```

[image: output2]

Third is make sure to not create a pdf (and I assume to skip sending the email too) when the row is already processed before.

**Step 1**: After setting the name with `setName`, check if the filename is already existing in the said folder.

```
if (ID !== null){
  newFile.setName(ID + ' ' + NAME)
} else if (PDF_FILE_NAME !== '') {
  newFile.setName(PDF_FILE_NAME)
} 

var filename = newFile.getName();
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(RESULTS_FOLDER_ID);
var files = folder.getFilesByName(filename)
var skip, file;
// Loop files that matches the filename
while (files.hasNext()) {
  file = files.next();
  // If filename is found in folder, then skip is true and 
  // will exit the while loop
  skip = filename == file.getName();
  if (skip) 
    break;
}
```

**Step 2**: Use that `skip` variable to determine if we should still do create the pdf and mail.

```
// if file is not existing
if (!skip) {
  // Self note PDF put in folder
  if (RESULTS_FOLDER_ID !== '') {
    folder.addFile(newFile)
    DriveApp.removeFile(newFile)
  }

  var subject = EMAIL_SUBJECT.replace('<<Name>>', NAME);
  var body = EMAIL_BODY.replace('<<Name>>', NAME);

  // Self Note: Email the new PDF
  if (recipient !== null) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(
      recipient, 
      subject, 
      body,
      {attachments: [newFile]})
  }
}
```

Comment: Dear @NaziA. Thank you so much for the feedback. I acknowledge the swapping script functionality.
Just 3 quick questions. I wanted to have the pdfs names the file name followed by the Name of the person. I haven't figured that out. a
Additionally, in the `var EMAIL_BODY = 'The email body'` I want to put the persons name i tried the `var NAME_COLUMN_NAME = 'Name'` but that failed.

Finally if a row has its pdf created, I would like to have that row skipped. how can I do this?

Your Expertise is appreciated

Comment: Hi @NirajBachheta, I have updated my answer and tackled all the additional questions. If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Dear @NaziA, Regarding the Question 3, the PDF keeps repeating to and creating in the Drive folder. if it is Possible, Please Email Me at nbachheta@gmail.com so that I can further illustrate the issue. Thank you again

Comment: Hi @NirajBachheta, feel free to post it as another question. Since the issue remaining is actually different from the original post and many can assist you, not just me. We keep the posts here as focused as possible. Just link the issue/post here after you post a new question so I can check it. Thanks.

Comment: Dear @NaziA, Just a quick one, I would like to add Country in the Email Subject. How can I do this. i tried various ways but failed